# how to link armadillo under linux ubuntu giving linking error

Tags: c++, linker-errors, armadillo, lapack

I have compiled the library armadillo installed it with sudo make install. 
Then I linked it with the following options

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-long-long -std=c++14 -fext-numeric-literals -Wno-cast-function-type -ffast-math -larmadillo -lblas -lm -llapack")
```

I get the following linking error
bayesian_estimation.cpp:(.text+0x4ad5): undefined reference to `dgemm_'

I also installed lapack and blas with sudo apt-get install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is for compile options (and even then...)
You should put these linker flags in differently:

```
target_link_libraries(my-target armadillo blas m lapack)
```